# How know the "admin" blog from wordpress multisite?

Tags: plugins, multisite, widgets

I'm try to construtc a multisite plugin and when I've the multisite list with all the blogs, I need to remove from this list the "admin" wordpress multisite.

For example: I've the multisites 'ids' like 1,2,3,4,5,6 and I need to know what 'id' have the administrator multisite and remove from the list.
Have Wordpress some function to give the id from "admin" wordpress multisite?

Comment: can you clarify this point 'have the administrator multisite'? i didn't understand.

Comment: Oh sorry... I think in the wordpress where you configure the multisite instalation. Where you have the access to configure your sub-sites, this Wordpress